# Apache Tiles 2.2.2 Pass value from tiles-config.xml to JSP

Tags: xml, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, apache-tiles

I have a common header in all the pages except for some pages where the right hand side of header which has some options. For eg, right hand side of my header will have option like : Block, Compose, Edit depending on the page. Is is possible to set this **headerShowIcons** from tiles-config.xml and then use it in rhsHeader.jsp.

**Is there any way by which I can pass some value from tiles-config.xml to rhsHeader.jsp and based on that value I want to show the option(ie, Block,Edit or delete)**

Example: if I want to show Compose option to user I just pass value(ie, headerShowIcons='compose') from tiles-config.xml and use it in JSP. If I want to show Block i will pass headerShowIcons='block' which will be read by rhsHeader.jsp to give display Block option. I hope this will be more clear

**tiles-config.xml**

```
<definition name="*/*/*/*/*/index" template="/{1}/{2}/xyz/{4}/layouts/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="lhsHeader" value="/{1}/{2}/xyz/s/headerWithBack.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="rhsHeader" value="/{1}/{2}/xyz/s/rhsHeader.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/{1}/{2}/xyz/s/myProfile.jsp" />
</definition>
```

**layout.jsp**

```
<!-- What should I add here to meet the requirement -->  
 <body>
   <header> 
      <div>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="rhsHeader"/>   
       </div>
   </header>
    <div>
       <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
   </div>
  </body>
```

**rhsHeader.jsp** is something like this :

```
 <tiles:useAttribute name="headerShowIcons" />
 <div class="RHS">
<ul>
<!-- I want to show the options (like- Block,Delete,etc) which will be passed from tiles-config.xml to rhsHeader.jsp (which here I have written it as headerShowIcons )-->
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${headerShowIcons  eq 'refine'}">
            <li><a href="#" class="refine">Refine</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${headerShowIcons  eq 'block'}">
            <li><a href="#" class="block">Block</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${headerShowIcons  eq 'edit'}">
            <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${headerShowIcons  eq 'delete'}">
            <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
                 <p>test</p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would chose a different way of doing it, but if it is what you want please see below

**tiles-config.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="app.base" template="/WEB-INF/views/default/default.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Not Found" />
        <put-attribute name="headerShowIcons" value="" />
        <put-attribute ..........>  
    </definition>
    <definition name="home" extends="app.base">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page" />
        <put-attribute name="headerShowIcons" value="edit" />   
        <put-attribute ..........>  
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**home.jsp**

```
<c:set var="var"><tiles:insertAttribute name="headerShowIcons"/></c:set>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${'refine' == var}">
          <li><a href="#" class="refine">Refine</a></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${'block' == var}">
        <li><a href="#" class="block">Block</a></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${'edit' == var}">
        <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${'delete' == var}">
        <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <p>test</p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

if you wish you can move this into layout.jsp and show your headers accordingly

Comment: I have edited the questions, I guess it will be more clear now.

Comment: @balboa_21 Sorry I  omitted part of the solution. See the edit

Comment: thanks for the help...it was much needed but it didn't solved my requirement. By the way I have found the solution and have written above.

Comment: Glad it helped. Btw both my solution and yours do exactly the same thing.

Comment: yes it does the same thing..but I dont know why, whatever value I was assigning to headerShowIcon was getting displayed in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the solution to do this, I believe it might helpful to someone with this kind of requirement :

we will have to use

in **headerLayout.jsp**

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="whatToShow"/>
  <header> 
    <div>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="lhsHeader" />
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="rhsHeader">
          <tiles:putAttribute name="whatToShow">${whatToShow}</tiles:putAttribute> 
        </tiles:insertAttribute>
    </div>
   </header>
 <div>
     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
 </div>
```

In **tiles-config.jsp**

```
 <definition name="Header.*" template="/{1}/layouts/headerLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="lhsHeader" value="/s/headerWithBack.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="rhsHeader" value="/s/rhsHeader.jsp"/>  
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="whatToShow" value="block" type="string"/>
</definition>
<!-- inside the definition under whatToShow, I just write whatever value(block,edit,delete,etc) I want to pass to the rhsHeader.jsp -->
```

in **rhsHeader.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<tiles:useAttribute name="whatToShow"/>
<div class="RHS">
<ul>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${whatToShow  eq 'refine'}">
            <li><a href="#" class="refine">Refine</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${whatToShow  == 'block'}">
            <li><a href="#" class="block">Block</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${whatToShow  eq 'edit'}">
            <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${whatToShow  eq 'delete'}">
            <li><a href="javaScript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
                 <p></p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS : I have used whatToShow instead of headerShowIcons